# Piano keys touching detection

Tags: arduino, piezoelectricity, music

I would like to make glove with pressure sensor on each finger to detect a moment when piano player touches a key. What kind of sensor should I use? I tried use simple buttons, but it is very uncomfortable for player :)

Comment: Do you want to detect a _press_ or a _touch_?

Comment: Why don't you use a midi keyboard?

Comment: Electronic keyboards still won't give you an event representing the very moment when the finger touches the key. A light-action keyboard provides a better approximation to that moment but there is still a delay, and it changes the whole feeling. Players also touch keys without playing a note, in anticipation of playing a note.

Comment: @CamilStaps Touch

Comment: @Andyaka I need to know which finger touches the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are just as valid as mine.  I'm just offering yet another option.

Use a piezo buzzer.  Something like what is in this picture:

[image: Piezo Buzzers]

When the piezo element is struck/stressed/etc it will produce a voltage spike that can be detected.  They are commonly used in drum machine pads, elevator buttons, etc.  They are fairly cheap, so you could easily get one and hook it up to an o-scope and experiment.

Comment: Thank you. I also just have tried piezo, and it works well. Now I need to find very small piezo sensor.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [resistive touch fabric](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2013/05/09/new-product-pressure-sensitive-conductive-sheet-velostatlinqstat/), although I don't know how sensitive it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [capacitive keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology#Capacitive_keyboard).

You didn't provide very much information about your system, so I can't give very detailed information on how to use this in your setup.

Some microcontrollers can control capacitive keys with a peripheral. There are also [controllers](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8287.pdf) available for these keys.

Comment: I have this glove and a light object from  5 section connected to glove. In our idea each finger should light up corresponding
section. We can not modify piano buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If the keys on your piano are conductive, you can use two pieces of tin foil and connect one to 5 V, another to your Arduino and put them on the glove but slightly separated so that when the finger touches the keys, the circuit is completed. A better way is to use either a piezo or if you are looking for a slightly more comfortable solution, resistive touch fabric wired up in a voltage divider circuit (Go to https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-dividers for a tutorial) with a zener diode of some sort should work with or without an Arduino. The resistive touch fabric only has a certain amount of sensitivity on its own, but in a voltage divider, you can measure increase the sensitivity.